# Xcode 9 autosave doesn't work if I quit my app using NSApp.terminate()?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, storyboard

I am building a macOS app using Xcode 9 with Swift 4. I want to save the size and position of my window, and recover it when users open it next time. Therefore, I gave my `Window` an autosave name `RectangleWindow` in the Storyboard.

If I quit my app using the `stop running application` button in Xcode, I can recover the size and position. However, it seems the autosave doesn't work if I quit my app using <kbd>command + q</kbd> or calling `NSApp.terminate(nil)`.

Is it the normal behavior? What did I miss to make autosave work?

Comment: Not normal. In fact, you're more likely to have the window restored if you "properly" (i.e. `terminate()`) the application. _However_, if something in your app's normal termination (say, something in `applicationWillTerminate(:)`) closes the window, then—technically—the window was closed when your app quit and it won't be restored.

Comment: `frameAutosaveName` and window restoration are two separate things. @JamesBucanek are you talking about `frameAutosaveName` or window restoration?

Comment: How do you open and close the window? What do you mean by "I can recover the size and position", do you want to set the frame in code?

Comment: I assumed you were talking about window restoration (which is where my mind is stuck, since I just spent a week getting it to work for several applications). In restoration, only windows that are open when the app quits get restored, and the restoration encapsulates its position and size. Autosave gets stored in the user preferences. I've seen other posts where user preferences aren't being saved for sand-boxed apps during development, so that might be an issue.

Comment: @Willeke My app only has one window, so it enters this window when launching. I don't close the window before termination. I mean I want the window to show up at the position where it is closed last time with the same size.

Comment: @JamesBucanek Yeah, it behaves weird and I don't know how to debug. Now I just manually store the window position and size to `UserDefaults` in `windowDidMove` and `windowDidResize` call backs, and restore them in `windowDidLoad`. It is not elegant, but it works.

Comment: In Xcode > `Attributes Inspector` > `Behavior` make sure `Restorable` is checked on.